# Unable to to deploy a Rails 5 VueJS app on ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, ruby-on-rails-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, webpacker

I'm trying to deploy a VueJS rails 5 app onto ElasticBeanstalk, I run into a command failed error on the EB instance when I try to.

I've tried a few suggestions like regenerating lock files but can't get past the error shown below:

```
Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...lation. 
error @nuxt/opencollective@0.3.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with 
this module. Expected version ">=8.0.0". Got "6.17.1" error Found 
incompatible module. info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install 
for documentation about this command. 

Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/09_yarn_install.sh failed. 
For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

What's happening here, and how can I get the deployment to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is that EBS uses a super old version of NodeJS like 6.X.

You'll need to add in your /.ebextensions some commands to remove the old and update. Below is part of a code I found that is specific towards upgrading NodeJS

```
# .ebextensions/fix_rails_6.config

commands:

  00_remove_node_6_if_present:
    command: "/bin/rm -rf /var/cache/yum && /usr/bin/yum remove -y nodejs && /bin/rm /etc/yum.repos.d/nodesource* && /usr/bin/yum clean all && rm -rf /var/cache/yum"
    ignoreErrors: true
  01_download_nodejs:
    command: "curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash -"
  02_install_nodejs:
    command: "yum -y install nodejs"
```